# Capistrano to restart Apache server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, unix, amazon-ec2, capistrano

I'm having an issue with Capistrano and my rails application. I have a simple rake task for my deployment:

```
 task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      execute "cd #{current_path}; rake assets:precompile"
      execute "sudo service httpd restart"
    end
  end
```

As you can see, after all the code is uploaded I precompile my assets and attempt to restart my server. For some reason this used to work fine, but now gives me as error:

```
DEBUG [e2f1f3dc] Command: sudo service httpd restart
DEBUG [e2f1f3dc]    sudo
DEBUG [e2f1f3dc]    : 
DEBUG [e2f1f3dc]    sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo
```

Any ideas how I could resolve this?

EDIT: Just in case you were wondering, the user that capistrano is logged in as is "ec2-user" with all the defaults that amazon assigns it with.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ssh to the server and then issue this command:

```
visudo
```

Then comment out the following line:

```
#Default requiretty
```

A better solution in case multiple users login to the system (bad idea, deployment systems should be managed by programs) is to disable TTY for a particular user like this:

```
Defaults requiretty
Defaults:%build !requiretty
Defaults:build !requiretty
```

The first line makes TTY mandatory for everyone. The second and third line exclude the build group and user from this requirement respectively.

Comment: I've read about that when searching google, but is that a security risk?

Comment: If multiple people connect to that system, then yes. In that case, you'd want the default behavior to be to require TTY to be present and exclude particular usrs or groups from the requirement.